# Creating rectangle over buffer circle with specified angles/rotation using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, polygon-creation

I have a layer that is a circle buffer around a point. What I want to do is create a rectangle around the circle, but have every rectangle be perfectly lined up N/S (0 degrees of angle/rotation). I have tried using Minimum Bounding Geometry, but the rectangles are all rotated a little different each time instead of all being the same.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcMap the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool does exactly as you ask.

If you do not have the appropriate license level (requires Advanced), there are Python techniques (see the 'square buffer' sample in Writing Geometries web help)